# How to write a c# console app that sets the env variables for that console?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a command to be executed from within the command line that will pull env variables from an external source (heroku) and update the environment for that command prompt.  My strongest language is C# so I decided to write a console app to do this.  I'm successfully getting the values from heroku, but not able to set the environment variables for the console.

Here are some of the options I've tried, but none are working.  Maybe it's not even possible from .NET

```
    foreach (var kvp in kvps)
    {
        // Works for user vars, but doesn't update the running console
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(kvp.Key, kvp.Value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

        // Seems to have no effect.  My guess is it only applies to the C# app itself, not the console.
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(kvp.Key, kvp.Value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        // Opens a bunch of windows but doesn't accomplish anything
        new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", "set " + kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value)
        }.Start();

        // Throws "file not found" exception
        new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"set", kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value)
        }.Start();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload Environment Variables in C# after launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363626/reload-environment-variables-in-c-sharp-after-launch)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson pretty close, but this is running directly from the console, and the answer below (both of them actually) is a solution that works in this use case.  In that question, it's a separate build environment which makes things more difficult (hence no approved answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process inherits its environment from the process that spawned it. You don't have the ability to alter the environment of another running process.

However, you can use this overload (assuming you have the rights)

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable( string , string , EnvironmentVariableTarget )
```

To change the registry and persist your environment changes after your process terminates.

One way to do what you want to do is this:

- Create a simple console app that writes your desired environment changes to `stdout`:

  ```
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
      DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now ;
      Console.WriteLine( "@set current_yyyymmdd={0:yyyy-MM-dd}" , dtNow ) ;
      Console.WriteLine( "@set current_yyyymm={0:yyyy-MM}" , dtNow ) ;
      Console.WriteLine( "@set current_yyyy={0:yyyy}" , dtNow );
      Console.WriteLine( "@set current_hhmmss={0:HHmmss}" , dtNow ) ;
      Console.WriteLine( "@set current_hhmm={0:HHmm}" , dtNow ) ;
      Console.WriteLine( "@set current_hh={0:HH}" , dtNow );
      return ;
  }
  ```
- Invoke that on the command line via `*.cmd` batch file wrapper like this (assuming your swanky new app is called `DateVars.exe`):

  ```
  @DateVars.exe > %temp%\_setDateVars.cmd
  @%temp%\_setDateVars
  ```
- From you command shell, execute your `*.cmd` file, which will fire off you app to set environment variables. When it finishes, the variables will be set for the duration of your command shell. In the above example, running the command `set curr` after the `*.cmd` file runs shows the following:

  ```
  C:\> set curr
  current_hh=17
  current_hhmm=1705
  current_hhmmss=170530
  current_yyyy=2013
  current_yyyymm=2013-09
  current_yyyymmdd=2013-09-24
  ```

It's the *nix way. Easy!

It should go without saying, that your executable and the batch file wrapper need to be in a directory located somewhere on your path.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your Visual Studio folder inside Common7\Tools.  You'll find a batch file vsvars32.bat, which is what's used to set the environment variables when you run a developer command prompt.  I don't think you'll be able to set the environment variables from within a .NET program, but you may be able to use a .NET program to generate a .bat file containing the relevant set statements pulled from your external source, then run the .bat file directly.